# SQL query to find customer that bought all of a type of product and also visited in a certain month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with these tables

```
employees(eid, name, telephone#, email)
customers(cid, name, telephone#, visits_made, last_visit_date)
products(pid, name, qoh, qoh_threshold, original_price, discnt_rate)
purchases(pur#, eid, pid, cid, ptime, qty, total_price)
```

I am trying to find the CID of each customer who has visited the retail business in October 2017 and has purchased all the products whose original prices are above $200.

The query below yields the correct CID, but it seems to be for the wrong reasons.

```
SELECT cid
  FROM purchases pur
       INNER JOIN (SELECT pro.pid
                     FROM products pro
                          INNER JOIN purchases pur
                          ON pro.pid = pur.pid
                    WHERE original_price > 200) t
       ON pur.pid = t.pid
 WHERE to_char(ptime, 'MM/YYYY') = '10/2017'
 GROUP BY cid
```

I believe this is finding all customers who bought a product with `original_price > 200` in October 2017. My initial thoughts were to use `ALL()`, but I haven't had any luck with that either.

Comment: I think you should search the purchasers, where no product with proice > 200 exists he didn't buy.

Comment: So you're saying check each row of purchases to see if it exists in a table of products with only original_price > 200?

Comment: I'm saying it's easier to write not exists subqueries in this case, like `select cid from customer where not exists (select (pid from product where price > 200 and not exists(select * from purchase where pid = .... `, if this performes good is another question...

Comment: Can you explain this point a bit more __customer that bought all of a type of product__ What do you mean by all type of a product ? 
Do you mean, if Product A had 100 quantity in stock, that customer bough all 100 of it ?

Comment: I meant that they bought all of a type of product given a condition. So in this case, the customer bought at least one of each product that cost $200 or more. Wording could have been a bit better on that in hindsight

Comment: Ok, i maybe wrong, jophab's approach maybe better, though i think it would at least be more readable to compare  count( distinct pids) form the purchases group by customer with the total number of available products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I understand you want something like this query -

```
select pur.cid
from purchases pur
join products pro
 on pur.pid = pro.pid
where pro.original_price > 200
 and month(pur.ptime) =  10
group by pur.cid;
```

**UPDATE**
You may try this query. This might fulfill your need though I didn't test it with populated data.

```
SELECT temp.cid,
COUNT ( * ) no_of_product
FROM (
SELECT
  p.cid,
  pt.original_price
FROM
  ( SELECT cid,pid FROM
    PURCHASES
    GROUP BY cid, pid
  ) p
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      pid,
      original_price
    FROM
      product
    WHERE
      original_price > 200
  ) pt 
p.pid = pt.pid
) temp
GROUP BY temp.cid
having count(*) > (select count(*) from product where original_price > 200) - 1 ;
```

Comment: I want to find the customers that bought **every** product with `original_price > 200` and has made any kind of purchase in October of 2017. This just find the customers who bought any item $200+ in October.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cid
  FROM purchases pur     
  WHERE to_char(ptime, 'MM/YYYY') = '10/2017' 
  AND pid IN (
              SELECT pid FROM products WHERE original_price > 200
             )
  GROUP BY cid,pid  
  HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM products WHERE original_price > 200)
```

Comment: as per OP, the `IN` condition should actually be `ALL`

Comment: That's correct, I want the customers that bought all products with `original_price > 200`. That's where I've had issues, trying to emulate the effects of an `ALL IN` keyword.

Comment: It's not @jophab because, in the current case, there is only one row selected and there are two products that have `original_price > 200`, so the `HAVING` clause is not evaluating to true.

Answer (score 1):

So, after reading some other materials and trying a few different things, I think I have a correct query. This is appears to be a query that can be solved with relational division and one way to achieve that is by utilizing nested `NOT EXISTS` queries. [This article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) talks about performing relational division in SQL in great detail and helped to clear things up a lot for me, so for anyone with a similar kind of query, read that article.

Here's the query that I believe now works properly

```
SELECT c.cid
  FROM customers c
       INNER JOIN purchases pur
       ON c.cid = pur.cid
 WHERE to_char(ptime, 'MM/YYYY') = '10/2017'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM products pro
                    WHERE pid IN (SELECT pro.pid
                                    FROM products pro
                                  WHERE original_price > 200)
                     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM purchases pur
                                      WHERE pur.cid = c.cid
                                        AND pur.pid = pro.pid))
```